# How can I override clone correctly?

Tags: apex, controller, custom

I have been trying to override the functionnality of the standard clone button.

Writing in a custom controller, I tried:

```
public PageReference clone() {
    new MyClass.MyException('HAAAAAA');
    return null;
}
```

But the compiler says *Method return types clash: clone()*

What is the `clone()` method signature ?

**EDIT**: How can I override clone correctly ?

Comment: clone() is a built-in method, so you are overriding the method here.  Won't you have to return a PageReference since your return type in your implementation of clone() returns that?

Comment: The return type is the class type itself so no casting is needed. Just change the name of your method to not be `clone`.

Comment: I've posted an answer which i think will address your question. One thing i would recommend, is changing the title of your question to "How can i override clone correctly?" rather than stating the error your getting in the title. This will help folks understand it today and in the future better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean to [override the standard **Clone** button](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_customize_override.htm)...

[image]

To do this you need to implement a [Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm) page using the [StandardController](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) and an [Extension Controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) which contains the **custom Apex clone logic**. The name of the method providing this is not important and you should avoid using **clone** as it is reserved for cloning Apex objects in general not records. The steps are as follows.

**Create a Apex controller, something like the following..**

```
public with sharing class CarCloneController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;

    public CarCloneController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) 
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
        // Fields being cloned
        this.standardController.addFields(new List<String> { 'Name', 'Make__c' });
    }

    public PageReference cloneCar()
    {
        // Record being cloned
        Car__c currentCar = (Car__c) standardController.getRecord();

        // Custom clone logic
        Car__c clonedCar = new Car__c();
        clonedCar.Name = currentCar.Name;
        clonedCar.Make__c = currentCar.Make__c;
        insert clonedCar;

        // Redirect to the new cloned record
        return new PageReference('/'+clonedCar.Id);
    }
}
```

**Create a Visualforce page, something like the following..**

```
<apex:page standardController="Car__c" extensions="CarCloneController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="{!Car__c.Name}" subtitle="Clone record confirmation"/>
        <apex:pageMessage severity="info" summary="Click Clone to confirm you wish to clone this record."/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!cloneCar}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**Navigate to the objects, Buttons, Links, and Actions list and override the Clone button.**

[image]

**Doing it without the confirmation page**

You can if you want perform the Clone immediatly without the prompt by changing the Visualforce page to look like this. However be warned that currently this presents a security risk known as [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), if this is not a big concern to you, you can use the following to replicate the standard user experience.

```
<apex:page standardController="Car__c" extensions="CarCloneController" action="{!cloneCar}"/>
```

If you want to know more about overriding standard buttons, custom buttons and Apex, this [blog will give you more information](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/). Salesforce tell us the ability to permit actions immediately without the risk of CSRF and without the confirmation page workaround is close on the roadmap.