# fire an apex trigger on opportunity while cloning a record

Tags: trigger

trigger to copy Opportunity Team when an Opportunity when the opportunity is cloned.

That can we copy the child records when we are cloning ...

Comment: User6833, could you be a more detailed in what you're trying to do and what is blocking you ? It's not entirly clear or obvious what your question truly is.

Comment: When i click clone (standard button) to clone an opportunity when a new opportunity is created i want to even the child records of opportunity to be added to the new opportunity that is created by cloning.I think this functionality is possible so can have a workaround to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to do a "deep clone" of the Opportunity. There are a number of different ways of doing that. See [How To Clone Opportunity With Extra Related Custom Objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48273/How-to-clone-opportunity-with-extra-related-custom-objects) and [How can I override clone correctly?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33662/how-can-i-override-clone-correctl) for two posts that should provide you with different solutions to what you're asking about.